# Does leaflet support wms tile layers in applications/openlayers formats?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, wms, leaflet

I am trying to create a tilelayer.wms overlay on top of a wfs base map and I wasn't sure whether leaflet allows the applications/openlayers type of format which I served up from geoserver or only images/pngs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With leaflet, you can add WMS services as tile layers on the map. There is some example code in leaflet api [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

```
var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
});
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I mean can the format where you have 'image/png' be 'applications/openlayers'?

Comment: No. WMS maps are dished out as images. Application/openlayers is not a valid format. see WMS specs http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms

Comment: Application/openlayers can be a valid format but it isn't what you want - it returns a complete html page containing an OpenLayers application inside it. It's mostly a short hand for the GeoServer layer previews that turned out to be handy for others to use.